# Problem detecting forward slash in preg_replace regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am running preg_replace across a string which may contain street numbers. The pattern I'm using is:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]*)/i
```

This works fine for numbers such as 1, 1a, 123 etc.

However it does not pick up street numbers like 1/54B

I tried to add a forward slash to the pattern like this:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\/]*)/i
```

But it isn't picking up numbers like 1/54B.

Any ideas on what I should be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
preg_replace('#([A-Za-z0-9/]*)#i', $repl, $subj);
```

Using alternate delimiters makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that in this example I had overlooked that the forward slash was being translated into URL friendly code (%2F) so

```
([A-Za-z0-9\%]*)/i
```

worked for this situation. Yup, I feel stupid.

Thank you to Matthew for his useful tip. Going to file that one away.